# Orders not moved with customer store transfer

Tags: magento-1.9, database, orders

Hi I ran a MySQL query to move some customers by changing their website and store id.

They have now moved however their old orders are still in the old store and not linked to their accounts!

If I click into an order there is no link on the customer so they are not linked up!

How can I relink them?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have moved only customer data.

You have to move **customer order data** as well

if you go to `sales_flat_order` table where you find `store_id` which is linked to old store because you have not changed the order data,